# How to have a List<string> with n amount of entries react to a button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I have the `list` where i have image location paths and i display the first one bt i have this `button` that when its `clicked` i want to move to the next `path` of the list. How can i achieve this?

First there is the code where i display the first image.

```
    protected void ShowPng(string pathPgnImg)
        {
            btnNextPage.Visible = true;
            string sImageName = "";
            
            string sImagePathImages = Server.MapPath("Anexos/");
            string pngFile = "";
            List<string> pngs = new List<string> { pngFile };
            string FileWithoutPath = Path.GetFileName(pathPgnImg);
            string fileWithoutPathAndExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FileWithoutPath);
            if(fileWithoutPathAndExt + "_pag" + LblHiddenImagePageNumber != fileWithoutPathAndExt + "_pag" + "" )
            {
                DirectoryInfo AnexoDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(PathForPdf);
                FileInfo[] filesInDir = AnexoDirectory.GetFiles(fileWithoutPathAndExt + "_pag" + "*.png");
                    
                
                    foreach (FileInfo foundFile in filesInDir)
                    {

                        pngFile = foundFile.FullName;
                        pngs.Add(pngFile);
                    }
                    pngFile = pngs[1];

            
                string sFileExt = Path.GetExtension(pngFile);

                pngFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(pngFile);
                m_sImageNameUserUpload = pngFile + sFileExt;
                m_sImageNameGenerated = Path.Combine(sImagePathImages, 
                m_sImageNameUserUpload);

                //Literal1.Text += "<img src=" + '"' + pngFile + '"' + "/>";
                imgCrop.ImageUrl = "Anexos\\" + Path.GetFileName(pngFile);

                if (m_sImageNameUserUpload != "")
                {
                    pnlCrop.Visible = true;
                    imgCrop.ImageUrl = "Anexos/" + m_sImageNameUserUpload;
                    Session["ImageName"] = m_sImageNameUserUpload;
                }
            }
}
```

In the foreach cycle i add all the paths into the `List`.

And i want to make this happen in this button click event.

```
protected void btnNextPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                     
            ShowPng(imgCrop.ImageUrl);
            
        }
```

But if there is a way of doing it just inside the `ShowPng function` im fine with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some sort of state variable which holds the index of the current image, then when you click the button you can update that state.

I dont think your ShowPng code should be performing all of the logic that it is.

You should be finding all the images found at the path in a single method, and showing them with another and again this should be stored in some class level property or state object.

```
private List<string> imagePaths = new List<string>();
private int imageIndex = 0;
```

In the method you have included add an item to the imagePaths list when you find a matching image.
then when you click your next button you would be doing something such as -

```
imageIndex++ //increase index by 1
imageCrop.ImageUrl = imagePaths[imageIndex]
```

Comment: Hello Chris thank you for the reply i tried what you said it gave me this error System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:   The index was out of range. It must be non-negative and smaller than the collection size.
Parameter name: index' on this button event line imageCrop.ImageUrl = imagePaths[imageIndex]

Comment: you need check imagePaths . if it does not have those path yet, get them. if have those path, then move to the next index, and assume does not reach the end of the index.

Comment: oh ok thanks done it, works now, thank you to the both of you.